# Listview Item Imageview on click Issue

Tags: android, android-listview

I have on imageview in listview.
I am using custom adapter to bind the data.
I am showing toast of a textview text of the same listview on imageview click.
But it is showing random textview text.
here is my code

```
  localfilename=tvlfilename.getText().toString();
  ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivnotificationpreview); 
   thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, localfilename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }});
```

Comment: Its because of recycling mechanism of ListView. Use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for maintaining the exact data which is clicked. [Have a reference blog of mine](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html)

Comment: so what should I do now?

Comment: Can you post more code - where do you retrieve the items index on click?

Answer (score -1):

put `localfilename=tvlfilename.getText().toString();` in `onClick()` method. you have to get localfilename value at time of click event

try this way

```
  ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivnotificationpreview); 
  thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        localfilename=tvlfilename.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(mCtx, localfilename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }});
```